# How to implement "Options" in iOS 13 Share sheet

Tags: swift, share, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios13, ios-sharesheet

In iOS 13 many different system apps (for example Photos and Safari) added "Options" to their share sheet. Users can select as what they want to export (URL / Web Archive) and sometimes even options (include All Photos Data).

How can this be implemented? I cannot find any documentation for this.

Currently my implementation is

```swift
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myText], applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = ...
MyViewController.shared?.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {})
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: There are no API changes for `UIActivityViewController` so that seems to be something only Apple apps can do.

Answer (score -1):

image.jpg file is what u have to select in that photos u took or in gallery.
use this code

```
let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")!

let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
    activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)

// This lines is for the popover you need to show in iPad 
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = (sender as! UIButton)

// This line remove the arrow of the popover to show in iPad
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.allZeros
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 0, height: 0)

// Anything you want to exclude
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
    UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
    UIActivityTypePrint,
    UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
    UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
    UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
    UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
    UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
    UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo
]

self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: nil)
```

Comment: That does not tell me how to implement custom options, though.